# apply css animation to specific html element using angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

please check first the demo on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXFysavaqw2EqlyiZgvT?p=preview).

My problem is: this animation will be applied to all elements in html, 
cause in css is defined .ng-enter .ng-leave etc.

I am trying to apply it to a specific class name. In my case, it's `<li class="specific">`

And in CSS I've tried following:

```
.specific.ng-enter /*(does not work)*/
.specific-ng-enter /*(does not work)*/
```

With these code above, I can add and remove items but without animation.

**How should the code be in css ?**

Comment: Your plnkr is not working. Please solve, so that I can see your prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are a couple of possible issues with the code:

1. You are using `ngRepeat` on your `<ul>` (I cannot be 100% sure that this is not what you want but it is highly improbable). `ngRepeat` will "repeat" (clone" the element it is on, so in your case you are creating multiple `<ul>` elements (instead of multiple `<li>` elements, as one would expect).
   Moving `ngRepeat` o the `<li>` will solve the animation problem and result in the intended HTML code (1 `<ul>`, multiple `<li>`).
2. Your CSS defined transition with every class, while it would suffice to define one rule:

   .top.ng-enter, .top.ng-leave {
       // ...define transitions here
   }
3. In order to avoid possible CSS specificity issues (especially later on, when your CSS grows in size and complexity), you should include the `.ng-enter/leave` class selector in the rules with `.ng-*-active`:

   // Instead of just: 
   .top.ng-enter-active {...

   // You should use:
   .top.ng-enter.enter-active {...
4. Finally, you can group identical rules together, to save space and make your code more DRY (e.g. `.top.ng-enter` rule === `.top.ngleave.ng-leave-active` rule).

---

Your final code should look like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul>
  <li class="top" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

/* CSS */
.top.ng-enter,
.top.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.top.ng-enter,
.top.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.top.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.top.ng-leave {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LDOjYZYXRrQAGTMpVE4h?p=preview)**.

Comment: I've tried to apply this animation to a table. Removing a row should be done with animation. I have inserted class="remove" in every possible tag, but it doesnt work. Can you help me on this? Code is on http://plnkr.co/edit/d7JGJljlfh8UdrPuVoxH?p=preview

Comment: @ng-User: Tables are a "different story" because of the way the rows are displayed (`display: table-row`). They can't have some porperties (e.g. margin) but you can play with others (e.g. opacity). If you want to be able to manipulate certain properties, you can temporarily set `display: block` but it isn't going to look very impressive. See an example **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xP8VhVLeg5xd1kz6hFsy?p=preview)**. BTW, if you fell this post better answers your original question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just give class to your `<ul>` like this.

```
<ul class="my-anim" ng-repeat="item in items">
   <li class="top">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQw2MRT9yqBoW00JjXEo?p=preview)

Comment: ah, not <li> but <ul> needs the class name. That was my mistake. Thanks  Jay !